# laravel TokenMismatchException for file upload more than 8MB

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, apache2

When i upload below 8MB it works fine. But when the file is more than 8 MB It shows this error

> (1/1) TokenMismatchException
>
> in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)
>
> at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>
> in Pipeline.php (line 148)

Comment: did you put CSRF-TOKEN in your form.

Comment: Token Mismatch is totally diffrent to size of file. it not showing while you select file above 8mb.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in php.ini file located in your php root directory.
Set it to your choice

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Comment: I have found the solution.
I have missed the csrf_token in the input field.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your file which you are uploading is smaller than the max upload size but more than the POST_MAX_SIZE. The input is truncated at the POST_MAX_SIZE which means that the csrf token is lost.

You can change these values in php.ini file. Make sure that both upload_max_filesize & post_max_size are same.